# How to detect when the user sets an active tracks

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I need my iOS sender app to be aware of any changes made by the user regarding the active tracks but I cannot find any way to do so.

When the app is registered as a GCKMediaController delegate, it is notified via the `mediaController(_:didUpdate)` method that a change has occurred and the list of active tracks can be retrieved but nothing indicates that the update deals with active tracks change.

Moreover, my app simply provides a UIButton to the GCKMediaController `tracksButton` and does not instantiate a GCKMediaTracksViewController so I cannot register anything as a GCKMediaTracksViewControllerDelegate.

The last resort would be for my app to implement a custom media tracks selection view controller but I would not want to have to do that.

Thanks for your help.